# unable to make signed apk in android using android studio ,getting error:

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip file 'E:\Ondoor Final Repository created on 08-02-2016\Project\projectname\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar'.

can anybody help me :

Comment: Have you checked https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210693&thanks=210693&ts=1463824240 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211156

Comment: this might be cause of spaces in the path

Comment: check the path in the exception. Check if the file exists on the file system

Comment: @SelçukCihan : i have tried this links too but the main thing is in both the link app-debug.apk is show but in my case its main.jar file which is failed to read zip file.